# Appropriate sentence/ Tense to be used for declaring something

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

Which sentence should I use when I pass the exam? I mean at the time of announcing the result.

a) I cleared the Exam. (Past Tense)

It refers to the past event of passing the exam. I mean results were declared first and then I am announcing to my family.

b) I clear the Exam (Present Tense)

It refers to the current status of passing the exam.

c ) I have cleared the Exam (Present Perfect Tense)

I think this is the correct sentence to be used because it is referring to a past event having an impact on the present.

Comment: "**clear** the exam" is  not used here in the UK. Here we say "**pass** the exam".  From what I can tell, the verb clear is only used in this sense in Indian English, and nowhere else. So, if your audience is international, don't use that verb!

Comment: @BillyKerr It ain't used in AmE either. pass/fail just like the uk.

Comment: @Lambie - yeah it's used in Indian English.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple past or past perfect, either works. There's no particular reason to prefer one over the other. This is often the case in English.

However, the verb "clear" wouldn't be usual here, at least in British English.

Comment: What is the present tense in this case ?

Comment: Um, it's labelled in your question.

Comment: It's used exclusively in Indian English.  Had to look it up on google ngram to find out where it came from.  It's never used in the UK, or at least would be considered highly unusual.

Answer (score 0):

If passing the exam has just happened and you are really excited about it, use the present perfect, because it has an effect in the present.

As soon as you mention when you passed, for example: yesterday, last week, this morning, use the past simple.

Comment: What is the present tense in this case ?